# SVG arc slips away as it completes it's arc

Tags: svg

http://codepen.io/andrewplummer/pen/pyjjbJ

I'm trying to make a simple arc for a graph. I've read up on "A a" arc in SVG and I believe I understand the specifics, but when the arc approaches its origin point it starts slipping to the right and I can't figure out why.

The main problems seems to be here: `<path d="M75 5 A70 70 0 1 1 71 6" stroke="#3f51b5"></path>`. As the closing point (`71 76`) approaches the origin (`75 5`) the arc starts to shift to the right. The pen shows more details... All browsers show this behavior so it doesn't seem to be a bug.

Comment: Circle with dash-stroke array, see: http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/15/

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clever too! Might use it instead next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's the call to `Math.ceil` that was causing this issue. It appears that even small changes in the final x/y position (the last 2 arguments to the svg A command) can have big effects on the resulting arc. When drawing larger arcs these smaller differences can have more exaggerated effects, so @Paul LeBeau's answer is somewhat correct. However, simply not rounding fixed the issue and renders perfectly so it seems that one arc will in fact do the trick, just don't round (rounding pixel values is kind of a force of habit for older devs used to crappy browsers).

Answer (score 1):

If you need accuracy, then don't try to draw a complete 360deg arc with one path arc command.  Because you don't specify the centre point when describing arcs, tiny mathematical inaccuracies between the combination of start point, end point and radiuses can cause the arc to shift around by quite a surprising amount.

I would suggest keeping your arcs to a maximum of 180 degrees.  For large radiuses you may want to go even lower, and limit it to 90 degrees.

Answer (score -1):

The arc command has two flags, the attached image should explain it.

Are you trying to draw a complete circle ?

Comment: What attached image is that then? Don't write questions in your answers, if you have questions use the comment facility.